# Any complete GUI interface for Mercurial?

Tags: gui, mercurial, version-control

I've tried TortoiseHG from the repositories, but it wasn't working at all.

Comment: You might want to be more descriptive about the problem you had with TortoiseHG.

Comment: Didn't react to any of the "menu" commands I selected.

Comment: They work for me on 10.10. Make sure that you also have `tortoisehg-nautilus` installed. Also nautilus has to be restarted.

Comment: Exactly as you told. Nothing happens when I click options or Clone... for example.. very weird. EDIT: Does work if you input the commands on console, not through menu.

Comment: @Queops Have you filed a bug about this problem?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10331/any-complete-gui-interface-for-mercurial

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following PPAs to your Software Sources, instructions are at the link endpoints:

[https://launchpad.net/~tortoisehg-ppa/+archive/releases [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~tortoisehg-ppa/+archive/releases)

[https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/releases [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/releases)

Or do it via the command line.

[ppa:tortoisehg-ppa/releases [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~tortoisehg-ppa/+archive/releases) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

[ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/releases) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tortoisehg-ppa/releases
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases
```

Install `tortoisehg`, and `tortoisehg-nautilus` if you want nautilus integration.

```
$ sudo apt-get install tortoisehg tortoisehg-nautilus
```

Use `hgtk` as though it were the usual `hg` command to get a GUI interface for each command (e.g. `hgtk status`), or use the interface provided in nautilus if you installed the requisite package.

Comment: Nice handy PPAs

Comment: When I try to install tortoisehg I got the following message : The following packages have unmet dependencies: tortoisehg : Depends: mercurial (< 2.5~) but 2.5-0ppa1~precise1 is to be installed Recommends: python-iniparse but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Doing this works fine: `sudo apt-get install tortoisehg tortoisehg-nautilus`

No need for PPAs anymore (Ubuntu 15)

Answer (score 20):

`hg view` is installed as part of the mercurial package, but not enabled by default to keep the package from depending on the tk toolkit. Install `tk8.5`, and the add the following to your `"$HOME/.hgrc"` file:

```
[extensions]
hgk=
```

Launch by running `hg view` in the repository folder.
[image]

Comment: I needed to put the path to hgk.py into `$HOME/.hgrc`, ie. `hgk=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hgext/hgk.py`.

Comment: I got "/usr/bin/env: ‘wish’: No such file or directory" and had to do `apt install tk`

Answer (score 2):

meld does a pretty decent job.  Just install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install meld
```

And run it with:

```
meld
```

Then select "Version control view" and point it at the directory with your repository.  It will show you all the changed files and you can view a visual diff by double clicking the file.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this only shows current changes, and can't display commit history.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install tortoisehg tortoisehg-nautilus`

Then just `nautilus -q` then browse to your project in the file browser