# How to install the tortoisehg in Ubuntu20.04

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install [tortoiseHG](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) with:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i tortoisehg_4.8.1-0.1_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package tortoisehg.  
(Reading database ... 172882 files and directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to unpack tortoisehg_4.8.1-0.1_all.deb ...  
Unpacking tortoisehg (4.8.1-0.1) ...  
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tortoisehg:  
 tortoisehg depends on mercurial (<< 4.9~); however:  
  Version of mercurial on system is 5.3.2-1+exp1.  
 tortoisehg depends on python-pyqt5; however:  
  Package python-pyqt5 is not installed.  
 tortoisehg depends on python-pyqt5.qsci; however:  
  Package python-pyqt5.qsci is not installed.  
 tortoisehg depends on python:any (<< 2.8); however:  
 tortoisehg depends on python:any (>= 2.7~); however:  

dpkg: error processing package tortoisehg (--install):  
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...  
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu2) ...  
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...  
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...  
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 tortoisehg
```

How do I resolve those errors?

Comment: TortoiseHg binary packages list Mercurial as a dependency, so it is usually installed for you automatically, as per https://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html However, https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/linux.html says you should be able to find Ubuntu packages at https://launchpad.net/~tortoisehg-ppa - . Did you add that ppa to your source repositories? See https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/InstallingSoftware

Comment: I suppose the problem is here:

tortoisehg depends on mercurial (<< 4.9~); however:
Version of mercurial on system is 5.3.2-1+exp1.

Comment: The real obstacle is python-pyqt5 : There is no "python2-pyqt5" for Ubuntu 20.04 .... so you cannot even build  tortoisehg manually. ( https://bbuseruploads.s3.amazonaws.com/d2dca878-d630-4df4-aca5-943486bcfd9a/downloads/ca7cb710-3b87-45ab-9292-db8ad1c03dae/tortoisehg-5.0.2.tar.gz?Signature=tttLzFlPC4f8umjo1Jj9Jh%2FiAPc%3D&Expires=1588075962&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA6KOSE3BNJRRFUUX6&versionId=IzHHHycUEoi3k1.QtWwP5W_nQthQSzYX&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22tortoisehg-5.0.2.tar.gz%22 )

Comment: I'm currently using jetbrains IDEs graphical interface for mercurial.. (mostly for viewing diffs) maybe you can do the same until someone fixes tortoisehg.
Sorry I don't have a better answer right now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install TortoiseHG with integration to Caja on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229849/how-to-install-tortoisehg-with-integration-to-caja-on-ubuntu-mate-20-04-lts)

Comment: @K7AAY How do I add the `launchpad.net/~tortoisehg-ppa`? The ways I tried it always came back with `Cannot add PPA ... user or team does not exist`

Comment: @KnudLarsen The accepted answer, which says how to get it and run it manually, says to do so with Python 3, so it must be compatible with that. So I don't see how the lack of a Python 2 PyQt package is a problem - a hypothetical thg package for Ubuntu 20.04 could just use the Python 3 PyQt package.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Update:
I now do have a working package. It is available on github:

https://github.com/glaure/tortoisehg4ubuntu

Please give feedback!

Old:
I do not have a working package or snap. But using these instructions, it is rather easy to get `tortoisehg` working from source.

1. Check that `python --version` returns a Python 3 interpreter. If not, you have to change the symlink `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3`.

   OK:

   ```
   $ python --version
   Python 3.8.2
   ```

   Not OK:

   ```
   $ python --version
   Python 2.7.18rc1
   ```

   Change the symlink:

   ```
   $ sudo rm /usr/bin/python
   $ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
   ```
2. `pip3` is needed to fulfill all the build dependencies.

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-pip build-essential
   ```
3. Clone tortoisehg repository.

   ```
   hg clone https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/tortoisehg/thg
   ```
4. Change into `thg` directory.

   ```
   cd thg
   ```
5. Install PyQt5.

   ```
   pip3 install pyqt5
   ```
6. Install `mercurial`.

   ```
   pip3 install mercurial
   ```
7. Install `Qscintilla`.

   ```
   pip3 install qscintilla
   sudo apt install pyqt5.qsci-dev
   ```
8. Lets build `tortoisehg` for inplace usage.

   ```
   make local
   ```
9. Start `tortoisehg`.

   ```
   ./thg
   ```

I got `tortoisehg` working on three different Ubuntu 20.04 installations using this recipe.

Update:
https://github.com/glaure/tortoisehg4ubuntu

Contains scripts for automating the tasks listed above..

Comment: Gunther, you was perfect and solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Your approach failed for me: ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.Qsci'```. Any ideas?

Comment: I found the issue on my setup: pyqt5 was provided by the ```python3-pyqt5``` package, so ```pip3 install pyqt5``` did nothing. Interestingly the ```pyqt5.qsci-dev``` package was not necessary.

Comment: @axxel thank you. I will add this to the instructions.

Comment: And one other minor improvement: instead of manually changing the ```/usr/bin/python``` symlink better ```sudo apt install python-is-python3```.

Comment: Since early August 2020, there are few other steps needed. This is caused by the "release" of Mercurial 5.5, with which Tortoise is apparently incompatible. So, change step 6 to "pip install 'mercurial==5.4'" and add a new step (8.5?) "sudo apt install python3-pyqt5.qsci" (I see @Illa Brik spotted this last one too)

Comment: The above worked for me, with a couple caveats. I had to pull the stable branch  (append `-r stable` to the `hg pull` command) rather than the main branch. And i had to add the `python3-pyqt5.qsci ` package suggested below by user @Ilya Brick.

Comment: You also need iniparse to edit hgrc files, so also do the following: `sudo apt install python3-iniparse`

Comment: Thank you for this.  But you also need iniparse so tortoise can read the .hgrc: pip3 install iniparse

Comment: i needed `pip3 install QScintilla`

Answer (score 4):

When I tried to do the flow [suggested by Gunter](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235209/527764) something went wrong and I got an error:

```
No module named 'PyQt5.Qsci'
```

None of the installation options proposed previously here worked.

I managed to eliminate it by running

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qsci
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from confirming that [the steps described by Gunther work well](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235209/527764), I want to add that you also need to install `iniparse` to ensure TortoiseHg work properly. It needs `iniparse` to parse and update the Mercurial configuration.

Either

```
sudo apt-get install python3-iniparse
```

or

```
pip3 install iniparse
```

Also, if you want to make TortoiseHg available as desktop application from menu or so, you can first copy `thg` into `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`. You must also copy the Python module `tortoisehg` inside the directory where you built TortoiseHg to one of the paths in `PYTHONPATH` ([PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) is the path where Python searches for module files). Otherwise, TortoiseHg won't start with the following error.

```
$ thg
No module named 'tortoisehg'
abort: couldn't find tortoisehg libraries in [/usr/bin:/usr/lib/python38.zip:/usr/lib/python3.8:/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload:/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages]
```

You can do:

```
sudo cp -R tortoisehg /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
```

Then add a file `~/.local/share/applications/thg.desktop` (for current user) or `/usr/share/applications/thg.desktop` (for system-wide usage).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TortoiseHg
Exec=/usr/bin/thg
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Mercurial;Development
```

Update to set the `Exec` to the correct path of `thg`.

Also see: https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/tortoisehg/thg/-/wikis/developers/Linux

Comment: Please, don't put comments as answers. What happens if the referenced answer gets removed or edited? You should provide a full answer or not answer at all. There will be a time when you have enough reputation to comment until it arrives just try to answer when you know the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For those running Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows Subsystem for Linux 2. Assuming you installed and launched an X Server on Windows (e.g. [Vcxsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/)), on Ubuntu do the following:

1. Configure the `DISPLAY` environment variable in `~/.bashrc`

```bsh
IP=$(grep -m 1 nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}') 
export DISPLAY=$IP:0.0
```

2. Compile TortoiseHg

```bsh
sudo apt install mercurial python3-pip build-essential pyqt5.qsci-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
pip install pyqt5 mercurial qscintilla iniparse
sudo apt install libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xkb1 libxkbcommon-x11-0
hg clone https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/tortoisehg/thg
cd thg
make local
```

You may want to install [WSL Windows Toolbar Launcher](https://github.com/cascadium/wsl-windows-toolbar-launcher) to launch TortoiseHg from Windows. In this case, create the file `/usr/share/applications/tortoisehg.desktop`

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TortoiseHg
Exec=/path/to/thg_repo/thg
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Mercurial;Development
Icon=/path/to/thg_repo/icons/thg_logo.ico
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to do this all with tortoisehg in a virtualenv.  So here is a guide to do it that way, along with the desktop file.  This is very much based on the guide in the [earlier answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235209/150), with some bits and pieces from other answers to this question.

First install the required packages using apt:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip python3-venv build-essential pyqt5.qsci-dev
```

Then create your virtualenv and start using it:

```
python3 -m venv ~/.venv/thg
source ~/.venv/thg/bin/activate
```

(You can create your virtualenv where ever you want.)

Install packages into the virtualenv:

```
pip install pyqt5 mercurial==5.4 qscintilla iniparse
```

Note I have pinned mercurial at 5.4 because at the time of writing tortoisehg does not work with 5.5

Then we can clone the thg repository and build it:

```
hg clone https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/tortoisehg/thg
cd thg
make local
```

At this point we can run it directly

```
./thg
```

Or we can run it from anywhere, without activating the virtualenv, by using the python from the virtualenv.  You could type the following at the command line, or put it in a shell script, say in `~/bin/`

```
$HOME/.venv/thg/bin/python path/to/thg/thg
```

If you want to launch it as a desktop app you can put the following in a file at either `~/.local/share/applications/tortoisehg.desktop` (just for your user) or at `/usr/share/applications/tortoisehg.desktop` (for all users of the system).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TortoiseHg
Exec=/home/youruser/.venv/thg/bin/python /home/youruser/path/to/thg/thg
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Mercurial;Development
Icon=/home/youruser/path/to/thg/icons/thg_logo.ico
```

Obviously update the paths on the `Exec=` and `Icon=` lines to match your actual path.

Comment: As of December 2020, TortoiseHg requires mercurial >= 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a snap package of tortoisehg.

`sudo snap install tortoisehg --edge`

(currently only available on edge (like alpha))